# Load the EXTJS build after the phongap deviceready event get called

Tags: cordova, extjs, cordova-3, extjs5

I have the EXTJS Application which working fine,I have started integration of the EXTJS with PhoneGap/Cordova.So here i want after the app launch take the IP address from device then i can start to load all the EXTJS files i.g. bootstrap/css on successful device ready.

As i tested its not fire/able to find the plugin until the device is properly ready it tries to call all the js same time so after first try to plugin it fails and then i receive the Deviceready event.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you need. Are you saying you want to wait for deviceready before loading Ext JS and your application?

Comment: yes u right. I am taking the server IP from native iOS code via plugin.and use that ip over the ajax request and store proxy. But if i directly load that data it not able to identify the plugin and throw undefined obj error.